# C# and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function reload() { window.parent.location.href = "loginPage.aspx"; }

</script>
```

I have the above JavaScript, how to call this with my code behind?

```
private void checkpageacess()
{
    if ((lpsContext)Session["sessionfContext"] == null)
    {
        //-------------------I want to call that java script here
        Response.Redirect(@"~\Logout.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorManager.Current.LpsContext = (lpsContext)Session["sessionfContext"];
    }
}
```

Comment: The language is called "javascript", not "java script" or "java".  (I've corrected your question, title and tags.)

Comment: When you say your "code behind", do you mean like servlet code?  C# code?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly call JavaScript code from C# code.  The latter runs on the server in response to a request and the former runs on the client after the server has finished processing and delivered the response.

What you can do, as @Darin Dimitrov showed in his example, is determine when in the C# code to deliver that JavaScript function to the client and set it when to execute.  This generally happens when the page is rendered, maybe with a short delay, in response to some kind of page event (such as a button click).

Naturally, this means that it has to happen via a post-back when responding to a page event, which may not be the user experience you're looking for.  Can you elaborate more on when this method needs to be called?  Keep in mind that interacting with the page and interacting with the server are two very different things.  All of the C# code is done executing before the JavaScript code is even available.  It's *highly* likely that what you want to do is in response to a page event and should be done entirely in JavaScript on the client-side, not from C#.

Comment: private void checkpageacess()
    {
        if ((lpsContext)Session["sessionfContext"] == null)
        {
          
           I------------- want to call that java script here ------------------
            
            Response.Redirect(@"~\Logout.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorManager.Current.LpsContext = (lpsContext)Session["sessionfContext"];
        }
       
        
    }

Comment: @Daniel Raj: Why do you want to call the JavaScript there?  What's it accomplishing?  When you perform the `Response.Redirect` on _the_ _very_ _next_ _line_ you're indicating to the client that it should initiate a completely new request anyway.  Why tell the client to go to one page and then immediately tell them to go to another?

Comment: I think he wants to call a JavaScript function after the user is redirected?  In which case, set a session variable before the redirect.  Then in the Logout's page load event, check the session variable and follow Darin's answer to register startup script.

Comment: He want to redirect **parent** page, which can indeed be done only with client side script..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) method:

```
public void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        GetType(), 
        "myscript", 
        "reload();", 
        true
    );
}
```

This will call the `reload` javascript function once the page is rendered on the client.

Comment: but i am using it in a function not in button click event. pls help me

Comment: @Daniel Raj in what function? Please show your code. If it is in the code behind how is this function triggered?

Comment: If you add a IsClientScriptBlockRegistered() check, I'll up vote this one.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with your current logic, as whatever JavaScript code you send to the browser will disappear without effect when you're calling `Response.Redirect` command.

One way around is have the client side `reload` function perform both actions: load different page in the parent window plus redirect the current window.

The code for `reload` will look like this:

```
function reload() {
   window.parent.location.href = "loginPage.aspx";
   document.location.href = "/Logout.aspx";
}
```

And your code behind:

```
if ((lpsContext)Session["sessionfContext"] == null)
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "auto_reload", "reload();", true);
}
```

(Yes, what Darin gave exactly, just in the right context :))

You might also consider making `checkpageacess` return boolean value that when false, abort any further actions.